# How to implement OnItemLongClickListener on ListView from array / json?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, onitemlongclicklistener

I have a movie list, and when I perform long press on a movie, I want to display a synopsis of the movie. I try to run this simple code, but it does't return a value.
PS: The json I made at https://app.subarnanto.com/api/inventory is not actually a movie list, I just learned to create an api on a nodejs and mysql for my school assignment.
Thank you.

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    String url = "https://app.subarnanto.com/api/inventory";
//    String url = "https://www.subarnanto.com/api/andri.json";
    ListView list;
    private List<MovieDataSet> listMovie = new ArrayList<>();
    private MovieAdapter movieAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        JsonArrayRequest jar = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                listMovie.clear();
                for (int i=0; i<response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject job = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        MovieDataSet mds = new MovieDataSet();
                        mds.setImageUrl(job.getString("image"));
                        mds.setJudul(job.getString("name"));
                        mds.setYear(job.getInt("serial"));
                        mds.setRating(job.getDouble("tag"));
                        listMovie.add(mds);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(MainActivity.this, listMovie);
                movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

                list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                       Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick:" + listMovie.get(i));

                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Anda menekan: " + listMovie.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       return false;
                   }
                });
           }
    }
```

[image: Pic 1 - setOnItemLongClickListener]

Comment: What does "doesn't return a value" mean? Did you debug and step through and confirm the `onResponse` callback is actually called?

Comment: Instead of the value of the movie description (what I wanted), it instead returned something like a variable. It returned something like this "Anda menekan com.lindawxx@somenumber". It should be "Anda menekan some-movie-sypnosis".

Comment: What does "it returned something like a variable" mean? What is "it"? Where is "it" returning "a variable". Please be clear in your description.

Comment: Hi @dominicoder sorry for not being clear, I want to take a screenshot but Android Studio now produces an error while installing apk to the phone, I can’t use AVD as my computer doesn’t support VTx. I’ll get back to you once I got it running on my phone, thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Hi @dominicoder, I've just uploaded an image. Have a look at the bottom. It should display a description, but it showed something else. Do let me know should you need any info. Thank you.

Comment: Your code says, you just show a toast message for performing longPress. Now, what's the main problem you faced? In toast message, it's showing the MovieDataSet object.

Comment: Hi @FaysalAhmed thank you for responding. If it’s a movie list, I want to show a short synopsis. If it’s a animal list, I want to show a brief description about animal. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Where actually you want to show the synopsis?

Comment: When I click the item

Comment: @EkoAndri is there any view that will show the synopsis? where is the synopsis value?

Comment: It’s from this url subarnanto.com/melvi.json. So I have to create another view to show this “synopsis” when I long click the item?

Comment: Sorry, the url should be https://www.subarnanto.com/api/melvi.json

Comment: Yes, you have to create another view to show the details.

Comment: Ok noted that. Thank you @FaysalAhmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code like below

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
               @Override
               public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick:" + listMovie.get(i));

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Anda menekan: " + listMovie.get(i).getSynopsis/*this from your MovieDataSet model class*/ , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   return false;
               }
            });
```

Comment: you are welcome ,@EkoAndri if my answer help you upvote my answer

Comment: Hi @SamRaju I upvoted your answer but I am below 15 reps so it won’t show up.

Comment: its okay @EkoAndri Happy Coding ;-)